# Volley DefaultRetryPolicy callback when all retries have been exhausted

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm using the following method to retry a post request every second at most 5 times

```
    postRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(1 * 1000, 5, 1.0f));
```

I need a way to listen for when all retries have been exhausted so I can trigger a callback and do some action in my app.

I see that I can do `postRequest.getRetryPolicy().getCurrentRetryCount == 5` but I need to somehow do this on a loop.

Comment: Wouldn't you just get an onError response when that occurs?  With a timeout exception as the error?

Comment: I would get one for every time it occurs but not when all of them have occurred - would you suggest keeping a count of that in a member variable where the onError response is?

Comment: That sounds like the simplest way to move forward.